# metadata protection for Monero usage on Mobile devices

Tags: kovri, i2p, metadata, android-wallet, ios-wallet

My understanding is that Kovri will use a C++ implementation of the I2P network to protect metadata.

I2P seems to be focused on computer users. Are there any plans to protect metadata  for Monero users on Mobile devices (Android and iOS) in the future?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While VPN and Tor usage is much higher that I2P usage on mobile devices today that is also the case for PCs.

There is already an I2P app for Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.i2p.android

I see no technical reason why Kovri could not eventually implement support for mobile devices.

Comment: While it is possible, I'm not sure how likely it is that I2P support will be added for android. I don't think many people will want to run a Monero node on their phone even if they can. Wouldn't people just use an android app to connect to their node on their computer at home?